# how to write a .htaccess redirect like stackoverflow does for its questions

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to write a .htaccess rule that would redirect someone asking for

```
http://mysite.com/questions/123/my-question-name
```

to

```
http://mysite.com/questions/question_handler.php?qid=123
```

Here's what i wrote so far (it's not working):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/questions/(\d+)/(.*)$ http://%1/questions/question_handler.php?qid=%2$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^http://([^/]*)/questions/(\d+)/(.*)$ http://$1/questions/question_handler.php?qid=$2`

Your `(.*)` was probably too greedy so it was using http://mysite.com/questions/123/my-question-name as the first group matched

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/?$ questions/question_handler.php?qid=$1 [NC,L]
```