# htaccess to achieve links like stackoverflow

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write a .htaccess redirect like stackoverflow does for its questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583106/how-to-write-a-htaccess-redirect-like-stackoverflow-does-for-its-questions)

Say a link to my page is like this...

http://example.com/test.php?id=10978&name=html-tutorial-for-beginners

How do i make it to

http://example.com/10978/html-tutorial-for-beginners

I have multiple pages like

http://example.com/more_test.php?id=1054758&name=how-to-use-htaccess

http://example.com/some_more_test.php?id=10324758&name=some-thing-good

Also how do i post from a form or a anchor tag ?

is it like action="http://example.com/test.php?id=10978&name=html-tutorial-for-beginners"

or action="http://example.com/10978/html-tutorial-for-beginners"

for anchor tags href="http://example.com/test.php?id=10978&name=html-tutorial-for-beginners"

or 
href="http://example.com/10978/html-tutorial-for-beginners"

How do i achieve it for multiple files like test.php, more_test.php some_more_test.php

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583106/how-to-write-a-htaccess-redirect-like-stackoverflow-does-for-its-questions

Answer (score 0):

Based on the your link modification i think that you want to make SEO freindly url in the core php files. Basically it would be each in MVC framework.

But still not impossible in code php

First step
Create index.php file or any other files which will be pointed each time on page call
Create the .htaccess file in which any page call request would be defined rules.
Below is .htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In index.php, we have check the request or url of page and based on it we can call file or action that is required [By extracting the query string].

May this will help you